# Laravel save() method not detecting custom primary key properly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update existing entries in my MySQL database with eloquent's 'save()' method, but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

the save() method is supposed to detect the record via primary key and update the record instead of trying to insert it right? what am i missing here?

here is the beginning of my user model:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

protected $primaryKey = 'objectguid';

public $incrementing = false;
```

this is how i created the users table: (laravel migration)

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->string('objectguid')->primary();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('displayname');
        $table->string('company');
        $table->string('department');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('phone');
        $table->date('start_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And here is my controller method:

```
public function pull()
{

    $users = $this->ldap->search([
        'objectguid', 'samaccountname', 'mail', 'title',
        'sn', 'givenname', 'displayname', 'department',
        'company', 'telephonenumber', 'whencreated'
    ])->get();

    foreach($users as $user)
    {

        $user->save();

    }
}
```

what is really throwing me off is if i use the `User::find(objectguidofrecordhere)` it works as expected and finds the record no problem.

Comment: It looks like you have duplicate users you are getting via `ldap->search()`.  Can you make sure each user there has a unique `objectguid`?  A reason you can use `User::find(objectguidofrecordhere)` is because all the users have been added once, it just didn't add the duplicates.

Comment: no, in active directory the objectguid is unique. i am not the one that creates those id's. thanks for your input though

Answer (score 1):

> the save() method is supposed to detect the record via primary key and
>   update the record instead of trying to insert it right?

I do not believe that is how the save method works. You need to query for a model to determine its existence or not, then act accordingly:

```
$user = User::find(1234);

if ( is_null($user) ) {
  // User doesn't exist
  $user = new User();
}
$user->someAttribute = 'taco';
$user->save();
```

If the user is `null`, then it doesn't exist in the database and you have to create a new object. Then update whatever attributes you want. Then save it.

As far as I know, save does not automatically determine if the objects exists already for you. I could be wrong if this is some hidden undocumented Eloquent feature though.

Comment: thanks. i don't know why i thought i remembered it automatically updating.

Comment: Yeah I don't think its possible since doing a `User::find(1234)` would give you a null object. Can't run `->save()` on a null object.

Comment: You can do `$user = User::firstOrNew(array('objectguid', '1234'));`.  That will check for an objectguid 1234 in the database and if it finds it, will return it.  If it can't find it, it will instantiate the user model for you then you can continue.

Comment: actually i found out why it's not working...since i'm not retrieving the model initially from the database using Eloquent, it is not setting the `exists` property to true in the model instance. I'm essentially populating the attributes of the user model manually when i retrieve it using LDAP, then saving to the database, thus the exists flag is not changed to true.

thanks you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did to get around this problem. Since I'm not initially retrieving the model from the MySQL database using Eloquent, it is not changing the `exists` flag in the `User` model's instance, therefore the `save()` method still believes the model does not exist in the database.

I added the following method to my `User` model to work around this problem.

```
public function checkExistence()
{
    if( ! is_null(User::find($this->objectguid)))
    {
        $this->exists = true;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And changed my controller's method to the following:

```
public function pull()
{

    $users = $this->ldap->search([
        'objectguid', 'samaccountname', 'mail', 'title',
        'sn', 'givenname', 'displayname', 'department',
        'company', 'telephonenumber', 'whencreated'
    ])->get();

    foreach($users as $user)
    {

        $user->checkExistence();
        $user->save();

    }

    return View::make('ldap.display', ['users' => $users]);

}
```

Again, thank you everyone for your input and helping me come to this solution.